# To extract specific information in the stack trace using regular expression

Tags: regex

I encountered a problem at http://regexone.com/example/6? You can view the problem by clicking the link. There was required a regular expression to extract the method name, filename and the line number from a particular stack trace in an android development application.

I used the following regular expression to solve the problem :

```
at widget.List.([a-zA-Z]+).([A-Za-z]+\.java).(\d{3,4}).
```

The expression works for the problem but i don't think its the correct regular expression as there is no hat(^) and dollar ($) included in it.

Comment: hat is beginning of string dollar is end of string, why do you need em?

Comment: so, is this not a string ? i guess it is...

Comment: Well, in other words if you put hat before you regex patter it will start search only at beginning of string, so ^[d+]$ will find string 1234, but would skip a123, or 123b

Comment: oh i got it now, thanks Sergio. And i found another way by using the hat and dollar, the regular expression which was applied in the above scenario was :

^.*\s+at widget\.List\.(\w+)\((\w+\.java)\:(\d+)\)$

Answer (score 0):

Dot and brackets are a special character in regular expressions and thus should be escaped:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile ("at widget\\.List\\.(\\w+)\\((\\w+\\.java):(\\d+)\\)");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher ("...at widget.List.makeView(ListView.java:1727)...");
m.find ();
System.out.println ("Method name: " + m.group (1));
System.out.println ("File name: " + m.group (2));
System.out.println ("Line number: " + m.group (3));
```

For me output is:

```
Method name: makeView
File name: ListView.java
Line number: 1727
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regex that can be used to solve this example:

```
^.*\s+at\s+.*\.(\w+)[(](\w+\.\w+)\:(\d+).*$
```

You should not use **widget.List.** in your regex (as you wrote in one of your comments above) as this will match only the classes from the widget.List package.